# sklearn metrics for multiclass classification

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I have performed GaussianNB classification using sklearn. I tried to calculate the metrics using the following code:

```
print accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Accuracy score is working correctly but precision score calculation is showing error as:

> ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting.

As target is multiclass, can i have the metric scores of precision, recall etc.?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The function call `precision_score(y_test, y_pred)` is equivalent to `precision_score(y_test, y_pred, pos_label=1, average='binary')`.
The documentation (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html) tells us:

> 'binary':
>
> Only report results for the class specified by pos_label. This is applicable only if targets (y_{true,pred}) are binary.

So the problem is that your labels are not binary, but probably one-hot encoded. Fortunately, there are other options which should work with your data:

`precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average=None)` will return the precision scores for each class, while

`precision_score(y_test, y_pred, average='micro')` will return the total ratio 
of tp/(tp + fp)

The `pos_label` argument will be ignored if you choose another `average` option than `binary`.

Comment: Great answer, one thing that the sklearn documentation lacks is to specify the order of classes when average = None. Nothing impossible to compute, but still it would be nice to include that too.

Comment: @TommasoGuerrini, totally agree. I ended up on this page because I can't figure out what order sklearn is outputting the precision scores....

Comment: @ml4294 thanks for your clarification I was wondering if it is the case for my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643736/incorrect-results-of-isolationforest)?