# Multiclass classification using Gaussian NB, gives same output for accuracy, precision and f1 score

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I am new to Python and classification algorithms. I am using GaussianNB for the multiclass classification of NSL KDD dataset, and in the end, I need to obtain the values of precision, recall, f1 score.

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, zero_one_loss
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

gnb = GaussianNB()
y_pred = gnb.fit(train_x, train_Y).predict(test_x)

results_nm = confusion_matrix(test_Y,y_pred)
#print(results_nm)
print(classification_report(test_Y,y_pred))
print(accuracy_score(test_Y,y_pred))
print("Precision Score : ",precision_score(test_Y,y_pred, 
                                           pos_label='positive',
                                           average='micro'))
print("Recall Score : ",recall_score(test_Y,y_pred, 
                                           pos_label='positive',
                                           average='micro'))
print(f1_score(test_Y,y_pred,average='micro'))
```

I followed the instructions in a similar question at 
[sklearn metrics for multiclass classification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890328/sklearn-metrics-for-multiclass-classification).

**The output as follows, but I am getting the same output for all three.** What could be the reason for that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen, as you can see in your confusion matrix, your micro average for all 3 metrics are in fact the same.

In the micro-average method, you sum up the individual true positives, false positives, and false negatives of the system for different sets and apply them to get the statistics. For example, for a set of data, the system's

```
True positive (TP1)  = 12
False positive (FP1) = 5
False negative (FN1) = 10
```

Then precision (P1) and recall (R1) will be (12/(12+5)) and (12/(12+10))

If FP1 == FN1, then they both will be the same.

and for a different set of data, the system's

```
True positive (TP2)  = 50
False positive (FP2) = 7
False negative (FN2) = 7
```

Then precision (P2) and recall (R2) will be the same.

Now, the average precision and recall of the system using the Micro-average method is

[image]

The Micro-average F-Score will be simply the harmonic mean of these two figures.

So, for specific values of **FP** and **FN**, it's possible for all these metrics to be the same. From the equation, we can say, if **FP1 + FP2 == FN1 + FN2**, then the micro-average precision and recall will be the same.

There are ways you can put values in the equation so that all 3 metrics give the same value, so you can try macro-average or weighted average.